# PHP with cURL for POST

Tags: php, api, post, curl

I have little function for get content result with cURL;
When i tried without POST, all working good, but with POST enabled, the result is null.

This code don't work:

```
function getAPI($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'shard=Apex');     
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.3) Gecko/20060426 Firefox/1.5.0.3");
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result; 
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

This code work but the request is not passed like a POST:

```
function getAPI($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'shard=Apex');   
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.3) Gecko/20060426 Firefox/1.5.0.3");
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result; 
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

I call this function with this command:

```
echo getAPI('http://world.needforspeed.com/SpeedAPI/ws/cmsbridge/news/rss/fr_FR');
```

You can also try with this URL

```
http://world.needforspeed.com/SpeedAPI/ws/game/nfsw/driver/levelkro/profile
```

This URL work only if shard=Apex (default shard=CHICANE for CHHICANE Server, but my profil is only available on Apex Server)

Comment: There is a lot left to the imagination on this one. Can you provide more details about what you are posting? When I post to this via command line I get `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<null/>`. So is this API meant to be posted to?

Comment: Have you tried passing as an `array` for you [`CURL_POSTFIELDS`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the SpeedAPI-manual (a simple Google-search) it would seem that the given URL does not accept the "shard" POST-parameter...

[SpeedAPI Manual for Get News RSS Feed](http://world.needforspeed.com/SpeedAPI/doc/get_news_rss.html)

You can however use a GET-request and use a shard-parameter where applicable according to the manual.

For example: http://world.needforspeed.com/SpeedAPI/ws/game/nfsw/driver/DRIVER_NAME/profile?shard=APEX (make sure you enter the shard-parameter in capitals)

Comment: You can view the entire SpeedAPI manual @ [http://world.needforspeed.com/SpeedAPI/doc/](http://world.needforspeed.com/SpeedAPI/doc/)

You can only use the parameters listed under "Input parameters". Everything else should be passed using the URI parameters. (Basically: don't use POST...)

Comment: I know the API, with socket I can make same request for GET and POST without problem (but it's long), just with cURL on POST I give an error.

Comment: Does it work when you use `echo getAPI('http://world.needforspeed.com/SpeedAPI/ws/game/nfsw/driver/DRIVER_NAME/profile?shard=Apex');` (with GET, not POST).
Substitute DRIVER_NAME with an actual name or you'll get the DRIVERNAME_NO_MATCH-error.

Comment: Try this url: http://world.needforspeed.com/SpeedAPI/ws/game/nfsw/driver/levelkro/profile  only work if shard=Apex because the profile is not on Chicane

Comment: Please try to refrain from "LMGTFY"-style answers. Either provide the answer or not, "simply google it" is beside the point.

Comment: I have searched before on google and php.net, I have tried some code (replace true for 1, with POSTFIELDS empty, etc...)

Comment: I have changed my original answer to include a solution that's more to the point.

Comment: lol, I have looked now all page of API docs, before the API work both, but now is just the leaderboard is on POST. Also an error on docs, thank Marty, on docs shared value 'Apex' is on normal/lower case, but when is and uppercase the value work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the parameter as an array like this instead:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('shard' => 'Apex'));
```

Comment: no sorry, return: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<null/>